# What does "Use windows fibers (lightweight pooling)" setting do in SQL Server 2014 server properties?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

What does "Use windows fibers (lightweight pooling)" setting does in SQL Server server properties?
[image]

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178074.aspx) you can find Microsoft's documentation on the subject.

Comment: I've read that, thanks, i'm looking for a more simpler explanation if one is available.

Comment: Another useful link from Microsoft that advises you to not use them: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175385%28v=sql.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: That article talks about SQL Server 2000.

Comment: TLDR: Fiber mode was intended for niche situations in which a scalability ceiling is hit due to UMS workers spending significant amounts of time switching between thread contexts, or switching the CPU into kernel mode and back again. Unless you have encountered this yourself, and have already tuned the system as much as possible using more obvious (and safer) techniques, I recommend that you stay away from fiber mode and focus your tuning efforts on other things. If you run into a situation where you feel strongly you need fiber mode, it's probably worth a call into Microsoft Product Support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> By default, SQL Server runs in what is called “thread mode.” What this means is that SQL Server uses what are called UMS (User Mode Schedulers) threads to run user processes. SQL Server will create one UMS thread per processor, with each one taking turns running the many user processes found on a busy SQL Server. For optimum efficiency, the UMS attempts to balance the number of user processes run by each thread, which in effect tries to evenly balance all of the user processes over all the CPUs in the server.
>
> SQL Server also has an optional mode it can run in, called fiber mode. In this case, SQL Server uses one thread per processor (like thread mode), but the difference is that multiple fibers are run within each thread. Fibers are used to assume the identity of the thread they are executing and are non-preemptive to other SQL Server threads running on the server. Think of a fiber as a “lightweight thread,” which, under certain circumstances, takes less overhead than standard UMS threads to manage.

[Source](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/fiber-lightweight-pooling/)

Comment: so when would you use one method over the other?

Comment: Just leave the setting alone. *IF* you are in a super rare situation where fibers would perform better than threads - there are most definitely bigger wins to be had.